# Upload a PDF in a web form, encrypt it then email it

Tags: email, pdf, encryption, upload

I have a client who is asking their users to download a PDF document to fill out that contains some pretty sensitive data inside it (SSN, etc.) and then they are asking them to take the form they've filled out and re-upload it to the site...but when they do this they want the file to email to them.

Now before you go off on rants about how it would be easier to just build an online form to collect this data...believe me, I've already been there. I've tried to convince them this is not the ideal way to go - but, to anyone who's ever worked with any client in the world knows, sometimes the client wants things done their way and that's the end of it.

That being said, I'd like to find a way to allow the user to upload the document, encrypt it (using some kind of key my client can use to decrypt it), email it to them, then delete the sucker off my server because I don't want that info sitting out there.

I am on a Windows 2003 server running IIS6. I have already been playing around with GPG4WIN without a whole lot of luck. I am open to ideas or solutions using ASP.NET or PHP.

Comment: PDF has encryption build into the standard. I am not sure about the full details though (in other words, I don't know it it would fit your use case) and I don't know if it is available in any form for ASP.NET and PHP. But maybe this is something to have a look at? Otherwise I would advise the CMS (cryptographic message syntax) container format.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a form that allows the user to upload a document and another one for obtain the password and the e-mail address from the user.

On the server-side, you can use a PDF library to set password provided by the user. (ASP.NET or PHP does not natively support PDF processing) After that, the original document can be deleted and the encrypted document can be mailed to the user's email address.

There are lots of free and commercial libraries that you can install on an IIS server. My company, Gnostice, has a royalty-free commercial PDF library that can do this. PHP may also have some installable libraries for encrypting PDF documents.